# TensorFlow Indices are not valid (out of bounds)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi i'am currently trying to run TensorFlow with own image data. 
But it crashes when i'am trying to run these function: its from mnist.py

```
def loss_fn(logits, labels):
    batch_size = tf.size(labels)
    labels = tf.expand_dims(labels, 1)
    indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, batch_size, 1), 1)
    concated = tf.concat(1, [indices, labels])
    onehot_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(
             concated, tf.pack([batch_size, NUM_CLASSES]), 1.0, 0.0)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,
                     onehot_labels,name='xentropy')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='xentropy_mean')
    return loss
```

with this error:

```
Compute status: Invalid argument: Indices are not valid (out of bounds).  Shape: dim { size: 100 } dim { size: 447 }
```

the number 100 is my batch_size and 447 is my number of classes.

i also try to solve that issue like here
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/194
changing the indeces line into this line:

```
indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(0, batch_size, 1), 1)
```

didn't solve my problem.
Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Can you share some of the context around the error message, including the name of the nose that failed? Also, can you print `logits.get_shape()` and `labels.get_shape()` to find out what the expected shapes of those tensors are?

Comment: @mrry Hi. I've tried your tip. my labels was empty. so i've started to debug.then i took a look inside my .tfrecords file i saw that the values from labels and depth field wasn't written. I used convert_to() function from this script: [link](https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py)

Comment: @mrry  At first i suppose there ist typing mistake inside this script in line 56 (dat.shape[0], num_examples) i think it should be (images.shape[0], num_examples) the second thing was that depth and labels values was empty inside the .tfrecords file. Only when i changend line 69 and 70 into [code] ('depth': _bytes_feature(str(depth)),'label': _bytes_feature(label),) i could see the passed depth and label value inside .tfrecords file. After that changes i ended up in another error but if can't solve it by myself i will post a new question. thx a lot for the hint.

Comment: You should take your comment that explains how you solved this problem and make it an answer. I know it did not get your code working but it is considered a valid answer here. By posting it as an answer it will help others because not all people look for answers in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error as well. And I realized my mistake. If you have 10 classes, your label values should range between 0-9, inclusive. The error was reproduced on the TensorFlow CIFAR10 example, used with [SVHN](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) dataset. Refer to question and answer below.

[TensorFlow CIFAR10 Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759227/tensorflow-cifar10-example?lq=1)