# cloudml retraining inception - received a label value outside the valid range

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-ml

I am following the flowers [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow) for re-training inception on google cloud ml. I can run the tutorial, train, predict, just fine.

I then substituted the flowers dataset for a test dataset of my own. Optical character recognition of image digits.

[image]

When training the model I receive the error:

```
Invalid argument: Received a label value of 13 which is outside the valid range of [0, 6). Label values: 6 3 2 7 3 7 6 6 12 6 5 2 3 6 8 8 8 8 4 6 5 13 7 4 8 12 5 2 4 12 12 8 8 8 12 6 4 2 12 4 3 8 2 6 8 12 2 8 4 6 2 4 12 5 5 7 6 2 2 3 2 8 2 5 2 8 2 7 4 12 8 4 2 4 8 2 2 8 2 8 7 6 8 3 5 5 5 8 8 2 5 3 9 8 5 8 3 2 5 4
```

The format of training and eval datasets looks like this:

```
root@e925cd9502c0:~/MeerkatReader/cloudML# head training_dataGCS.csv
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/TrainingData/0_2.jpg,H
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/TrainingData/0_4.jpg,One
gs://api-project-773889352370-ml/TrainingData/0_5.jpg,Five
```

The dict file looks like this

```
$ cat cloudML/dict.txt
Eight
F
Five
Forward_slash
Four
H
Nine
One
Seven
Six
Three
Two
Zero
```

I had originally had labels like 1,2,3,4 and /, but I changed them to character strings in case they were special characters (especially /). I can see a somewhat similar message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933846/tensorflow-indices-are-not-valid-out-of-bounds), but that had to do with 0th based indexing.

What's strange about the message is that there are indeed 13 label types. Somehow tensorflow is looking for only 7 (0-6). My questions is what kind of formatting error might make tensorflow think there are less labels then there are. I can confirm that both the testing and training data 80-20 split have all the label classes (though in different frequencies).

I'm running from recent docker build provided by google.

```
`docker run -it -p "127.0.0.1:8080:8080" --entrypoint=/bin/bash  gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:local-20161227
```

I am submit the training job using

```
  # Submit training job.
gcloud beta ml jobs submit training "$JOB_ID" \
  --module-name trainer.task \
  --package-path trainer \
  --staging-bucket "$BUCKET" \
  --region us-central1 \
  -- \
  --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/training" \
  --eval_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval*" \
  --train_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/train*"
```

Full error:

```
Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, Received a label value of 13 which is outside the valid range of [0, 6). Label values: 6 3 2 7 3 7 6 6 12 6 5 2 3 6 8 8 8 8 4 6 5 13 7 4 8 12 5 2 4 12 12 8 8 8 12 6 4 2 12 4 3 8 2 6 8 12 2 8 4 6 2 4 12 5 5 7 6 2 2 3 2 8 2 5 2 8 2 7 4 12 8 4 2 4 8 2 2 8 2 8 7 6 8 3 5 5 5 8 8 2 5 3 9 8 5 8 3 2 5 4 [[Node: evaluate/xentropy/xentropy = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT64, _device="/job:master/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](final_ops/input/Wx_plus_b/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd, inputs/Squeeze)]] Caused by op u'evaluate/xentropy/xentropy', defined at: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 545, in <module> tf.app.run() File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 308, in main run(model, argv) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 439, in run dispatch(args, model, cluster, task) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 480, in dispatch Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 187, in run_training self.args.batch_size) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 278, in build_train_graph return self.build_graph(data_paths, batch_size, GraphMod.TRAIN) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 256, in build_graph loss_value = loss(logits, labels) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 396, in loss logits, labels, name='xentropy') File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1544, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits precise_logits, labels, name=name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 2376, in _sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits features=features, labels=labels, name=name) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op op_def=op_def) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2238, in create_op original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1130, in __init__ self._traceback = _extract_stack() InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Received a label value of 13 which is outside the valid range of [0, 6). Label values: 6 3 2 7 3 7 6 6 12 6 5 2 3 6 8 8 8 8 4 6 5 13 7 4 8 12 5 2 4 12 12 8 8 8 12 6 4 2 12 4 3 8 2 6 8 12 2 8 4 6 2 4 12 5 5 7 6 2 2 3 2 8 2 5 2 8 2 7 4 12 8 4 2 4 8 2 2 8 2 8 7 6 8 3 5 5 5 8 8 2 5 3 9 8 5 8 3 2 5 4 [[Node: evaluate/xentropy/xentropy = SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, Tlabels=DT_INT64, _device="/job:master/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](final_ops/input/Wx_plus_b/fully_connected_1/BiasAdd, inputs/Squeeze)]]
```

Everything looks okay in my bucket

[image]

And saving my log events.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify `--label_count 13` when you submit your training job.  That flag should go after the in the second group of flags after the `--`, since it needs to be passed to the code you're executing, and not to gcloud/Cloud ML.

The issue is that the TensorFlow training code needs to know how many output logits to make before it starts stepping through the data; so it cannot inspect the intermediate files from the preprocess step.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help. Are there other docs I should be looking at? Looking here https://cloud.google.com/ml/reference/commandline/jobs/submit/training, not seeing that flag. Where should I look for IMPLEMENTATION-ARGS. I recognize this is still in beta.

Comment: Updated my answer.  The flag was inside model.py which has nothing to do with CloudML but about the Tensorflow code you're running!

Answer (score 0):

The flags after the -- model specific and are specified in [model.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/trainer/model.py#L47) file:

```
def create_model():
  """Factory method that creates model to be used by generic task.py."""
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  # Label count needs to correspond to nubmer of labels in dictionary used
  # during preprocessing.
  parser.add_argument('--label_count', type=int, default=5)
  parser.add_argument('--dropout', type=float, default=0.5)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--inception_checkpoint_file',
      type=str,
      default=DEFAULT_INCEPTION_CHECKPOINT)
  args, task_args = parser.parse_known_args()
  override_if_not_in_args('--max_steps', '1000', task_args)
  override_if_not_in_args('--batch_size', '100', task_args)
  override_if_not_in_args('--eval_set_size', '370', task_args)
  override_if_not_in_args('--eval_interval_secs', '2', task_args)
  override_if_not_in_args('--log_interval_secs', '2', task_args)
  override_if_not_in_args('--min_train_eval_rate', '2', task_args)
  return Model(args.label_count, args.dropout,
               args.inception_checkpoint_file), task_args
```

Note you can change things like label_count, dropout, max_steps, etc., to affect the model training.

HTH.