# Retraining Inception and specifying label_count = 2 but receiving three scores instead of two

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I have modified the [flower retraining code](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-classify-images-with-tensorflow-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow) to have label_count =2 as shown here:

`gcloud beta ml jobs submit training "$JOB_ID" \
      --module-name trainer.task \
      --package-path trainer \
      --staging-bucket "$BUCKET" \
      --region us-central1 \
      -- \
      --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/training" \
      --eval_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval*" \
      --train_data_paths "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/train*" \
      --label_count 2 \
      --max_steps 4000`

And I have modified dict.txt to have only two labels.

But the retrained model outputs three scores instead of two as expected.  The unexpected third score is always very small as shown in this example:

KEY PREDICTION SCORES

Key123 0 [0.7956143617630005, 0.2043769806623459, 8.625334885437042e-06]

Why are there three scores and is there a change one can make so the model outputs only two scores?

Note: I have read the answers from Slaven Bilac and JoshGC to the question “[cloudml retraining inception - received a label value outside the valid range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601620/cloudml-retraining-inception-received-a-label-value-outside-the-valid-range)” but these answers do not address my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the "label" we apply to images that had no label in the training set.  The behavior is discussed in this comment in model.py line 221

```
    # Some images may have no labels. For those, we assume a default
    # label. So the number of labels is label_count+1 for the default
    # label.
```

I agree it's not a very intuitive behavior, but it makes the code a little more robust against datasets that are not as cleaned up!  Hope this helps.